# Phising in Outlook for Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, outlook, phishing

Somehow, some of the emails I send are marked as "phishing" by Outlook in Windows Vista. Can you point me to resources that describe how this works? I'm not phishing and I do not understand what triggers this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

usually it happens if your links do not appear to be the same as the text they are made with. Such as a Bank One text being linked to an IP address. If there are a lot of links, and especially IP addresses, this can happen. Also, any hidden tags or any extra HTML that doesn't appear to be doing anything can do this. Another idea is if there are lots of images.

But, like Martynas said, posting the emails that are marked as phishing would help us better diagnose it.

Also note, some email newsletters and such sent my Microsoft from Microsoft.com are marked as phishing, too. So it's not just you.

Answer (score 0):

it would help if you pasted your message here.. It is difficult to say, but maybe you have some hidden links for example that might trigger such behaviour.

m